# vueJS app not interpolating curlies

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Creating my first "hello world" app using VueJS and while I'm getting no errors, the basic interpolation I was expecting from the templating is not working. Can anyone help me figure out what I'm missing:

**index.js:**

```
const App = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    title: 'Hello World',
    message: 'lorem ipsum'
  },
  computed: {},
  filters: {}
});

console.log('loaded app');
```

**index.html:**

```
<script src='node_modules/vue/dist/vue.min.js'></script>
<script src='./index.js'></script>

<div id="app">
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <p v-html="message"></p>
</div>
```

If I go into the chrome console I can test that my **App** is indeed a Vue object:
[image: vue object]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a browser's parser encounters a `script` tag, it will load and execute it before parsing the rest of the page. So, while your script does create a Vue instance, it is not associated with the `#app` div, because the parser is not yet aware of it.

For your Vue instance to load correctly, you need to move your `index.js` script tag to be after the `#app` div:

```
<div id="app">
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <p v-html="message"></p>
</div>

<script src='./index.js'></script>
```